# Implement several order relations for one class?

Tags: c++

Which is the best way to implement several order relations for only one class? I have an idea with the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) but I'm not sure that's a good idea. And if there is not a best way, why?

Comment: your question is too vague. can you elaborate? a simple example would be nice

Comment: What does "best" mean to you with regard to this problem?

Comment: I did some Java before. And we can use CompareTo or Comparator. And I'm wondering how simulate the behaviour of Comparator with the tools of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a functor class and initialize a member with the order relation you want to use. Have `operator()` use the member to decide the ordering of the two operands.

```
class Ordering
{
public:
    Ordering(int method) : _method(method) {}
    bool operator()(const MyObject & first, const MoObject & second) const
    {
        switch(_method)
        {
            case 0:
                return first.name < second.name;
            case 1:
                return first.age < second.age;
            // ...
        }
    }
    int _method;  // an enum would be better
};

std::sort(myobjs.begin(), myobjs.end(), Ordering(selected_method));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Strategy is a better way here, and I'm not pretty sure that a switch structure is a good idea (imagine, 1000 comparison methods in one switch... Too heavy, isn't it?)

So let A, a class which need a method comparison.

I suggest to create one class per method, which instance will be A's component.

For instance :

```
class A{
    private:
    //Some attributes
    Comparator<A> comp_;

    public:
    //Some methods (including constructor)
    bool operator()(const MyObject & first, const MoObject & second) const
    {
        return comp_.compare(first,second);
    }
     void setComparator(Comparator<A>& comp){
        comp_ = comp;
    }
}


//Forgot the syntax about template. So there is a template with one parameter
class Comparator{
     public:
     //Constructor

     //To overwrite on subclasses
     virtual bool compare(T& first, T& second) = 0;


}
```

With that configuration, you can easily add a method, without modifying A, just set the right comparator at any moment of program's execution.